# Not able to launch IE browser in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

Below is my code to launch IE browser and http://google.co.in page.

```
    File file = new File("C:/IEDriverServer/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://myruat.corp.webex.com/US/buy/signup.html";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am getting this below error:
4235 [main] INFO org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
4235 [main] INFO org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - Retrying request

**Please let me know how to rectify.**

Comment: I have downloaded IEDriver.exe and placed it in C:/IEDriverServer/IEDriverServer.exe. And I have added "selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar" as JAR in eclipse.

Comment: Check the below link. It should be able to help you.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3700

Answer (score 0):

did you set InternetExplorerDriver in your path environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
// Simply give the path in the setProperty

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "absolute_path");

//(absolute_path = Full path to the exe file of Internet Explorer)

// Ex : System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\ \testing\ \IEDriver.exe");

// Use double slash instead of single slash.


WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\ImportantSeleniumTools\\IEDriverServer.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

In System.setProperty give the location where you have kept InternetExplorer server file.